# Working with nested javascript objects returns empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have an application in which I am trying to register a user. In my middleware implemenation I have the code which creates a user object when they enter their first and last name, email, and password. However when I console log the new user object, those properties aren't updated. Just console logging the firstName it reutrns undefined. In my schema, the first name, last name, and email are nested.

I already tried using dot notation to access that specific property within the schema.

**User Schema**

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    empID: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userInfo: {
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            trim: true 
        },
        firstName: {
            type: String, 
            trim: true
        }
    },
    contactInfo: {
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
            unique: true,
        },
        phone: [{
            home: {
                type: String,
                trim: true
            },
            mobile: {
                type: String,
                trim: true
            }
        }]
    }
```

**User Route**

`router.post('/register', UserController.createUser);`

**User Controller**

```
exports.createUser = (req, res, next) => {

console.log("Before creating user");

//Creates new user
let newUser = new User({
   firstName: req.body.firstName,
   lastName: req.body.lastName,
   email: req.body.email,
   password: req.body.password
});

console.log(req.body.firstName);
console.log(newUser.toJSON());
```

Comment: `console.log(req.body.firstName);` returns `undefined` ?

Comment: Yes it does. And the entire object only shows which inner objects have an array in them

Comment: Can you log req.body?
In the user constructor you should nest the accordingly to your schema. Such as `userInfo.firstName: req.body.firstName`

Comment: `console.log(req.body);` returns a `{ }`. I tried that and it says that a ',' is expected

Comment: how you make request call ?

Comment: I think when you are calling the `'/register'` route, you are missing the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no example of your app.js file i'm shooting in the dark here...
try to use:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: Sorry about that, I did use body-parser. I just commented out `app.use(bodyParser.json());` now when I `console.log(req.body)` it displays everything I inputted in the form field